# How do you get a C-130 after the required rank?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Besides buying it, how do i get a C-130? I used to. Now a stunt plane spawns. Thanks!

Comment: It isnt random spawning?

Comment: Also, when you say required rank... are you asking this for online purposes?

Comment: You can't.  You get specific vehicles for specific ranges of rank.  When you rank up and the vehicle changes then that's what you get.  The only way is to randomly happen across one that spawned because of another player (eg. steal it from them :D) or buy it.

Comment: raid the military base?

Answer (score 1):

If you're online, you can (almost) always find one at the LS Airport: go to the airport and hop the fence via the dumpster on the left side. Directly across the runways is a hanger with a C-130 in it, unless it was recently stolen or destroyed. If you don't see it as you approach, **keep going**, it usually takes a few seconds to render and I usually only see it once I get maybe 20-50 feet from the hanger entrance.